# update same record which fires a trigger

Tags: oracle

I want to update the same record using the trigger which fires due to insertion of that record.

When I try to do that using the following code it gives an error

```
DROP TRIGGER CONTROLLER_UPLOADER;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CONTROLLER_UPLOADER

after insert ON CONTROLLER for each row

begin

    UPDATE CONTROLLER SET STATUS = 'STARTED' WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM CONTROLLER);

end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DROP TRIGGER CONTROLLER_UPLOADER;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CONTROLLER_UPLOADER

BEFORE insert ON CONTROLLER for each row

begin

    :NEW.STATUS := 'STARTED';

end;
```

Note "BEFORE" not "AFTER".